primeng p-calender size dialog calender issue
I used <p-calender from PrimeNg the issue is the size of the calender when i resize the navigator to 60% it will be visible but if the zoom of the navigator is 100% the input of the calender become invisible 
can we help me i tried with this code it show the calender not stuck to the input
<p-calendar 
    [(ngModel)]="date1" 
    [showIcon]="true" 
    [iconDisplay]="'input'" 
    [showOnFocus]="false" 
    inputId="icondisplay" 
    [showTime]="true"
    inputId="start_date"  
    dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
    [placeholder]="'jj/mm/yyyy hh:mm'" 
    styleClass="scale-calendar" 
    /> :host ::ng-deep .p-datepicker {
        transform: scale(0.9); /* Adjust the scale to your desired value */
      }


You can solve it in two ways:

You can also play with the positioning of the picker overlay, lets take your p-calendar and add a class to it, lets call it calendarContainer for example

<p-calendar 
    [(ngModel)]="date1" 
    [showIcon]="true" 
    [iconDisplay]="'input'" 
    [showOnFocus]="false" 
    inputId="icondisplay" 
    [showTime]="true"
    inputId="start_date"  
    dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
    [placeholder]="'jj/mm/yyyy hh:mm'" 
    class="calendarContainer"
/>

And now, let's make the styling
.calendarContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.calendarContainer  > .p-datepicker {
  top: calc(100% + 60px + 10px) !important;
}


100% as we want it to be at the bottom
60px is the height of our calendar input
10px is the padding of the calendar input

Which will result in

Another way if you like to show it as a popup, you can add the touchUI property to the Calendar.
Which will look like this:


I tried using the CSS class, but I didn't see any difference. The problem has not been resolved.

Did you add the css style in your scss file ? if you did, and you saw it applied in the devtools, what are the overrides that it made our styles ignored ?
